# Django Form: Default Value in one of the fields

Tags: python, django, django-forms

This is my form:

```
class FriendRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Friend
```

my model:

```
class Friend(models.Model):
    user1 = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='frienduser1')
    user2 = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='frienduser2')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user1', 'user2',)
```

In the template, how can I set user2 to be the ID based on who's profile page I am on? So if I am user1, and I am on user2's page (where this form loads in the html), I want user2 in the form to be set properly **from the html template**. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot update the database from a template unless you create a template context processor for it. This needs to be done in your view. Please post your relevent section of the urls conf and the view

Answer (score 0):

You can't set anything in templates but assume that you actually meant corresponding `view`. If so, you can set initial value for the form easily:

```
def profile_view(request, user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    form = FriendRequestForm(initial={'user2': user})
```

Comment: unfortunately, I dont have access to user2 from the view.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know which `User` model class you are using, but I'm assuming it is django's default `User` class. In that case, you can get the currently logged in user using `request.user`, and use that to populate the template field.

```python
# views.py
def foo(request):
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    # TODO: check this is a valid user
    render(
        request, 
        'template.html', 
        {
            # pass this user's id as a template variable
            # or pass the entire user object itself
            'user1_id': user.id, 
        })
```

```jinja2
# template.html
<div id='user1_field'>{{ user1_id }}</div>
```

IMHO, explicitly passing in required data is better than passing the entire `request` object in to the template like this:

```python
from django.template import RequestContext        
def foo(request):
    return render_to_response(
        'index.html', {'form': form, }, 
        context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```